# How can I make toggleClass("hover") fade in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I've been googling to no success.  I would like a part of my page to fade in when I hover over it.

Here's my css:

```
.status .admin {
    display: none;
}   
.status.hover .admin {
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's my .coffee script:

```
$('.status').hover (event) ->
    $(this).toggleClass("hover")
```

Comment: Are you sure its .status.hover and not .status:hover?

Comment: For fadeIn effect.. try  `$(this).fadeIn(3000)` instead of `$(this).toggleClass("hover")`

Comment: You can achieve this without jQuery by using `.status:hover .admin` in your css.

Answer (score 2):

For this task it makes sense to go with pure CSS with transitioning opacity:

```css
.status .admin {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
    transition: all .7s ease;
}   
.status:hover .admin {
    display: inline;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
    Status
    <span class="admin">Admin</span>
</div>
```

Comment: One might only add that OP might need browser prefixes like -moz or -webkit.

Comment: @Sossenbinder You are right, -webkit- prefix is probably needed (if old Android is supported). moz is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS3 like this:

```
.status .admin {
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
}

.status:hover .admin{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```